# Probability that a sample belongs to one of two populations to use with Bayes theorem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayes-theorem

Suppose we have two equally sized samples from two different groups, e.g. healthy and sick people. We measured some continuous variable on them, and we assume the underlying populations are normally distributed. We can estimate the populations of healthy and sick people by calculating the means and stds, and make two PDF functions.

Then suppose another single person got measured, but we don't know if he/she is healthy or sick, and want to assign them to one of the groups. I plot it like this:

[image: Two population PDFs and an unknown sample]

I also know the marginal probabilities of the two groups occuring in the world, lets say people of the group 2 form only 1% of total population.

Lets say:

- Event A is that the sample belongs to one of the groups.
- Event B is that I measured the value belonging to the unknown sample.
- A can be "divided" into disjunct events C1 (sample belongs to group 1) and C2 (sample belongs to group 2).

Then from what I understand, I formed this using Bayes theorem:
[image: Usage of Bayes rule]

#### Main question:

Where do I get these last two conditional probabilities *numerically*?

- I know I can't read *probability* from a PDF function.
- I am not interested in "greater than" or "lesser than" probabilites from CDF functions.
- I really don't want to mess with "ring like surroundings" and "infinitely small distances" (unless I have to :) ).

#### My ideas for solution:

- One idea was to take the probability densities from the PDFs at the unknown value, and make a "ratio" out of it, like odds, that the sample falls in one group over the other. **But I am not sure if I can compare probability densities like that.**

[image: Probability densities at the unknown sample's value]
[image: Odds that the sample falls in one or the other group?]

(f1 and f2 are the probability densities group 1 and 2, p1 and p2 *could* be the odds that the sample falls in one group or the other? That is the question.)

- If I substitute the conditional probabilities with the probability densities from PDFs, it obviously won't give me a probability value in the end, but could I use the results just to compare them in between, to assign the sample to the higher one?
- Can I understand the Bayes rule usage in this case such as that the marginal probabilities would *scale down* the PDF functions by factor or 0.01 and 0.99?

Thanks in advance for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density you are looking for is a mixture of the original normal densities. And the mixing coefficients are the marginal probabilities of each group, 0.01 and 0.99

Edit: Also, $P(B|C_i)$ are the normal densities of each group that you already found/determined.

In my opinion, the language used in this question is a little bit inconvenient, but can be easily fixed. The question asks for a density, so we are looking for a function $f$ such that $P(X\in B)= \int_B f(x)dx$, where $X$ is the random measurement.

It's clear that $P(X\in B) = P(X\in B|C_1)P(C_1) + P(X\in B|C_2)P(C_2)$, and the problem states (in prose) that $X|C_i$ follows a normal distribution with known parameters. So $P(X\in B|C_i) = \int_B \phi(x;\mu_{C_i},\sigma_{C_i}^2)dx$, where $\phi$ is the density of a normal distribution.

In conclusion, $P(X\in B) = P(C_1)\int_B \phi(x;\mu_{C_1},\sigma_{C_1}^2)dx + P(C_2)\int_B \phi(x;\mu_{C_2},\sigma_{C_2}^2)dx = \int_B P(C_1) \phi(x;\mu_{C_1},\sigma_{C_1}^2) + P(C_2)\phi(x;\mu_{C_2},\sigma_{C_2}^2) dx$

which proves that the density we are looking for is exactly $P(C_1) \phi(x;\mu_{C_1},\sigma_{C_1}^2) + P(C_2)\phi(x;\mu_{C_2},\sigma_{C_2}^2)$.

Comment: A proof and a general argument would be welcome.

Comment: But... I was not looking for the densities, but for the probabilities. To get an answer in the form of, for example "28% that it belongs in one group, 72% that it belongs to the other" if possible.Thanks for the answer but it is a bit too technical for my level, I don't understand how to apply it. I should just multiply the density values at X with the marginal probabilites?

Comment: Probabilities of what?
You can compute the probability that a measurement falls in a set B by integrating the given density over B.

If you want the probability that a measurement falls in B, given that it belongs to group 1, just integrate the density of group 1 over B.

And if you want the probability that a measurement comes from group 1, given its measurement, use the formula that you already listed, because you have all the ingredients.

Comment: I think I understand now. First you have to define what is the event B that you are interested.
B can not be "Measurement = 0.35", because that is an event with probability 0 and you can't condition on such events. You have to choose which event are you interested in modelling, which could be " Measurement is less than x" or "Measurement is between a and b".
So the real question you have is, perhaps, what is a right choice for B. The right choice of B will depend on how do you plan to use this. If it is for diagnosis, a common approach is to try different cutting points x and check accuracy.

Comment: That is what I was questioning - if getting the probability of "Measurement = 0.35" is possible in any way. If not, can I use the probability densities and put them in the Bayes formula, knowing the result will not have the dimension of probability, but it can be used to compare between two groups? Because Bayes formula normally operates with probabilities and not densities.
Edit: This problem comes from an old exercise from a statistical analysis course I help teach. It was fishy and I was trying to understand it.