# Probability of new sample belonging to one set or another

Tags: statistics, bayes-theorem, sampling

I have a stochastic event with two possible outcomes ($A$ and $B$). I also have two measurement techniques, a direct and an indirect one. The direct one can tell me exactly the outcome, but it implies interrupting the process.

The indirect one measures an intermediate variable $x$, which also has some variation. From previous experiments, I know that if the outcome is $A$, then the measured values of $x$ would present a normal probability distribution with mean $\bar{x}_A$ and standard deviation $\sigma_A$. Similarly, if the outcome is $B$, then the measured values of $x$ would present a normal probability distribution with mean $\bar{x}_B$ and standard deviation $\sigma_B$.

Given this information and a new measurement $\hat{x}$ form an unknown process outcome (which I know must be $A$ or $B$), I need to compute what is the probability of the outcome being $A$ or $B$.

I saw this other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277385/probability-that-a-sample-belongs-to-one-of-two-populations-to-use-with-bayes-th) with a similar question, but the answer seems overly complicated since I need to implement this in a computer for online classification of the samples.